# APK with native code crashes

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle

I have a native code that i compiled with ndk-build to an exe and it runs perfectly on the device.

Then i created a simple apk, added the c sources to the jni folder, configured the gradle.build's and when i launch the apk it calls the native function but at some point the app crashes.
I think i misconfigured the gradle.build scripts.

Can anybody review them ?

Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -DNDEBUG --all-warnings --extra-warnings
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/

LOCAL_MODULE    := iovyroot
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c getroot.c flex_array.c sid.c offsets.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a armeabi-v7a
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "com.mymodule"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName = "mymodule"
            CFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni/include").absolutePath)
            CFlags.add("-O3")
            CFlags.add("-DNDEBUG")
            CFlags.add("--all-warnings")
            CFlags.add("--extra-warnings")
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            stl = "stlport_shared"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

**EDIT:**
kmsg dump.
[last kmsg dump](http://pastebin.com/95vWe0EW)

Comment: You haven't included any information related to the actual crash, like the backtrace.

Comment: @Michael, hi i've added the event log if it helps.

Comment: That's just looks like a Java exception that occurs after the native crash. We need info about the native crash. For starters, what is the line of code that crashes?

Comment: @Michael hey, i've added the kmsg dump before the crash. Hope it helps.